# Grammatical error added in edit

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, grammar

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752199/finding-a-limit-of-a-sequence-in-mathbbr2) originally said "The question is to find all the possible limits of (1/n,0)." This was edited to "It is to find all the possible limits of (1/n,0)." While the edit also included other changes that improved the question, this portion of the edit introduced the pronoun "It" with no antecedent. When I [suggested an edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1001061) restoring "The question" in place of "It", it was rejected. I also tried to change "I begin to find the open set" to "I begin by finding the open sets". I don't understand why people are insisting on having the question be in broken English.

Comment: It looks to me as though there were multiple edit suggestions submitted nearly simultaneously.  Your edit suggestions seem to have been a bit minor?  Your edit was likely rejected as "too minor", while another editors suggested edit were approved.  See the final edit review [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2752199/revisions)

Comment: Note that typically, on one user can accept or reject an edit; it typically takes two such users.  Also, occasionally the OP themselves edits which may make the suggested edit irrelevant.

Comment: @amWhy *Adding* grammatical errors to a question seems rather poor form to me, and correcting such does not strike me as "too minor".

Comment: 52 more points from now, and you won't have to wait for approval.  But that doesn't mean that your edits might in the future be over-ridden by an edit submitted one second before yours.

Comment: I am not arguing that adding errors is Okay, but there were numerous actors acting nearly simultaneously, and it is hard to know what any editor had access to while they worked to edit.

Comment: Try to submit the edit suggestion again. But IMO one or two grammatical mistake IS a minor mistake and thus the edit is minor. Whether or not it is TOO minor probably depend on who is reviewing your suggestion. (Is that post is old, probably I would reject the edit too since there is no point to bump an old post just to fix grammar).

Comment: Also, FYI, sometimes a the OP (asker of the question) may be very offended about edits, and hence edits may be undone by the OP.  That doesn't mean the edits were poor; it just means they were overridden by another editor, or the OP themselves.

Comment: After reading the post I suggest you not to submit your edit. That post is missing contexts (those two comments) that OP should clarify.

Comment: In this situation pointing out the issue of pronoun "it" having no antecedent by a Comment might be a good encouragement to the OP to perform an edit, potentially achieving clarifications to some other issues (i.e. context).

Answer (score 3):

Your edit was perfectly fine, and the initial edit should not have been accepted (at least without additionally correcting the errors it introduced).  Editors and reviewers are human and sometimes make mistakes (or don't speak English perfectly).  That's all there is to it.